# How to reset array index after unset key in foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, foreach, unset

I am using `unset` to remove the particular object from the array with my conditions. But after unset, I am getting an object rather than an array. I tried to use `array_values` to rearrange the index, but it's not working for me. Please help me to resolve this issue. Below is my code:

```php
$empId = '100'; //just for example.
foreach($jsonData['data'] => $key as $value){
    if($value['emp_id'] == $empId){
        unset($jsonData['data][$key]);
    }
}
after loop code//
return $jsonData;
```

after unset data, it gives me an object. I tried with `array_values`, `array_merge` but it's not working for me.
I tried to replace `array_splice` with `unset`, but it's not removing data.

Comment: Unsetting an array element cannot produce an object. Please share all the relevant code (how you decode the JSON and whatever changes you may be doing after this loop that unsets elements).

Comment: using json_decode(json_encode($data),true); before foreach loop @El_Vanja

Answer (score -1, accepted):

key emp_id is as string, not as index.
your code has unset emp_id.
alternatively, you may use array_map function and then use array_values to reindex your array.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 serious syntax errors in your code.

This is what it should look like:

```php
<?php

// Some dummy data
$empId = '100';
$jsonData = [];
$jsonData['data'] = [
    'key' => ['emp_id' => 'value'],
    'key2' => ['emp_id' => '100']
];

// Fixed foreach loop
foreach($jsonData['data'] as $key => $value) {
    if ( $value['emp_id'] == $empId ) {
        unset( $jsonData['data'][ $key ] );
    }
}

print_r($jsonData);
```